# Typo3 Form Factory not calling finisher

Tags: forms, typo3, extbase

I am trying to add a form within my custom extension. In order to implement that I am creating the form with the form factory. The form is being displayed correctly, but it is not working as expected. The problem is, that the finisher is not being executed and no email is being generated and sent out. Any ideas how to fix that?

Here is the form factory class:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types = 1);

namespace Ready24\Ready24Ext\Domain\Factory;

use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility;
use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Validation\Validator\NotEmptyValidator;
use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Validation\Validator\EmailAddressValidator;
use TYPO3\CMS\Form\Domain\Configuration\ConfigurationService;
use TYPO3\CMS\Form\Domain\Factory\AbstractFormFactory;
use TYPO3\CMS\Form\Domain\Model\FormDefinition;

class NotifyFactory extends AbstractFormFactory
{

    /**
     * Build a FormDefinition.
     * This builds a FormDefinition manually for notification Form,
     *
     * @param array $configuration
     * @param string $prototypeName
     * @return FormDefinition
     */
    public function build(array $configuration, string $prototypeName = null): FormDefinition
    {
        $prototypeName = $prototypeName ?? 'standard';
        $configurationService = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ConfigurationService::class);
        $prototypeConfiguration = $configurationService->getPrototypeConfiguration($prototypeName);

        $form = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(FormDefinition::class, 'NotificationForm', $prototypeConfiguration);
        $form->setRenderingOption('controllerAction', 'perform');

        $page1 = $form->createPage('page1');
        $name = $page1->createElement('name', 'Text');
        $name->setLabel('Name');
        $name->addValidator(GeneralUtility::makeInstance(NotEmptyValidator::class));

        $email = $page1->createElement('email', 'Email');
        $email->setLabel('Email');
        $email->addValidator(GeneralUtility::makeInstance(NotEmptyValidator::class));
        $email->addValidator(GeneralUtility::makeInstance(EmailAddressValidator::class));

        $form->createFinisher('EmailToSender', [
            'subject' => 'Email from Sender',
            'recipients' => [
                'recipient@company.com' => 'Company'
            ],
            'senderAddress' => 'sender@domain.com',
        ]);

        $this->triggerFormBuildingFinished($form);
        return $form;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override the default form renderingOptions with the attribute "overrideConfiguration" in the formvh:render Viewhelper.

```
<formvh:render
factoryClass="YourClass\FormFactory" 
overrideConfiguration="{
renderingOptions: {
controllerAction: 'YourAction',
additionalAttributes: {data-attribute: 'YourAttribute'}, 
additionalParams: {tx_param : {hello: 'world'}}
}
}" />
```

For me this works fine with the controller, but unfortunately the additionAttributes are not shown in the rendered form in the HTML source, even though they are present in the factory up to the return point.

Comment: Thanks for the message.
But still, the defined controllerAction would be called from my own extension controller and not from the form extension.
So the form will not be submitted correctly. I would need to implement the standard behaviour of a form by myself…